# Is it poor design to have a company logo prominently appear twice on the main page of a website?

Tags: website-design, logo

I'm building a website for a new product, but the name of the product is also the name of the company. So I would love to have a small version of the company logo at the top left of the webpage (for consistency among other pages in the site), but then also the headline needs to direct attention to it as well, ie: "This [product/company name] is the best!".

Comment: Difficult to give any meaningful feedback without seeing it, but there are definitely ways of doing this that will look OK... https://us.coca-cola.com

Comment: Nice link, not sure which company it is though ;)

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't poor design. Unless, of course, the execution isn't done well.

Answer (score -1):

a good way to execute this would be to make one a watermark, subtle in the back ground somewhere on the page.

Comment: How does this answer the question being asked?